# External command on unsaved buffer

Tags: external-command

Is it possible to pipe an unsaved buffer to an external command and then replace the buffer by the command’s output?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the "filter" command,`:!`, which like most commands can be prefixed with a range:

```
:{range}!cmd
```

If you prefix this with a range, it will pipe those lines to the command's stdin, and replace those lines with the program's output. In this case you want to use `%` as the range, which means the entire buffer. For example:

```
:%!sort
```

You can find the Vim documentation with [`:help :range!`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#%3arange%21).

Comment: Very helpful. I use this to format long SQL queries to be more readable, e.g. open vim, paste the raw SQL string, then inside vim, I run `:%!sqlformat --reindent --keywords upper --identifiers lower -`

Answer (score 1):

Yes that should be possible. One possibility: the `system()` function takes as optional argument the input to be used for the external command.