# What does :%! mean?

Tags: command-line

I saw an editor command which started like this:

```
:%! sort
```

What does that mean? Specifically, the `:%!`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
:%! command
```

pipes the current file's contents to `command`'s stdin, and replaces the file's contents with `command`'s stdout.

So, `:%! sort` is pretty much the same as (from a shell) `cat file | sort > tmp && mv tmp file`.

Answer (score 11):

From [`:help :%`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#%3a%25):

```
%       equal to 1,$ (the entire file)        *:%*
```

From [`:help :range!`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#%3arange%21):

```
:{range}![!]{filter} [!][arg]               *:range!*
            Filter {range} lines through the external program
            {filter}.
```

That is, `%! sort` and `1,$! sort` are equivalent and they pass the text in the current buffer, from line 1 to the last line (that's what `$` stands for), through the external `sort` command. After that, those lines are replaced by the command output. [This](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/5428/6698) is another
explanation by @Carpetsmoker

That's useful not only for sorting a file. See some other examples here:

- [How to use an external command in Vim to modify selected words and lines?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/319/how-to-use-an-external-command-in-vim-to-modify-selected-words-and-lines)

Comment: I still don't understand what this means for the above example I've given, how does it interact with the command line?

Comment: @theonlygusti, you might want to also look at `:help filter`.  An excerpt: *"A filter is a program that accepts text at standard input, changes it in some
way, and sends it to standard output.  You can use the commands below to send some text through a filter, so that it is replaced by the filter output.
Examples of filters are "sort", which sorts lines alphabetically...."*